# How to efficiently listening(binding) to thousands of ports on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, tcp, network-programming

We are designing a TCP server to listen/bind to thousands of ports in Linux.

The traffic per second go though each port would be very little, so we are focusing on efficiently selecting from sockets.

Just binding to these ports and using poll or epoll on each socket maybe OK. However, we are pursueing a more resource efficiency design, for example, carefully design an IO threads model that can handle tens of thousands of sockets, while not costing too much CPU.

Any suggestions are welcome!

PS:

1. We are using Java, and Netty in this situation seems to be overkill. Is there any lightweight network framwork more suitable?
2. `iptables` are off the table, we simply can't use it.

Comment: Why would you be listening on thousands of ports? Are you really implementing thousands of different network protocols (HTTP, FTP, SMTP, SSH, ...)?

Comment: You need to start by looking at the available syscalls, like tomtzook's suggestion of `select`, to see what hook(s) would best suite your needs. *Then* you can figure out the proper way to interface with those syscalls via Java (and potentially implement something yourself with JNI if what you need isn't available).

Comment: Whole idea is wrong: system will be permanently overloaded due to so many permanently opened sockets. Each biding will hold an inode, similar to opened file, each OS has restrictive and finite number of simultaneously opened files ( inodes ) https://medium.com/@muhammadtriwibowo/set-permanently-ulimit-n-open-files-in-ubuntu-4d61064429a

Answer (score 2):

When working with a lot of ports, a really resource-efficient solution is `select`. The `select` function is a syscall which allows processing multiple input sources, and handling only those who have received data. It was added to Java with the `java.nio` package (JDK 7).

You may combine it with an `ExecutorService` to process only the needed channels, while preserving threads.

Read further:

- [Select in Java](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2073344/use-select-for-high-speed-networking.html)
- [Select man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)
- [Executor Services](https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial)